# HA proxy, how to add dynamic header to incoming request based on request URI

Tags: haproxy

We need to add a header to incoming requests processed by HAproxy.  However, each header needs to be composed of uri elements.
If the request is "http://myserver/system/apple/watch"
the header needs to be "Host:applewatch.com" where .com is static.

I am aware of "set-header" command, I just need to extract the second and the third URI elements via REGEX, string them together, and add static field .com.

Is there a way to save a URI element to a variable via regex and then reuse this variable as a header part?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
http-request set-header ASDF %[path,word(2,/)]%[path,word(3,/)].com
```

or

```
 http-request set-header ASDF %[path,regsub(^/system/,''),regsub(/,''),regsub($,'.com')]
```